# Why can't I perform rewrite tactic here?

Tags: coq

I have already a theorem

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m:nat,
  n = m ->
  n + n = m + m.
```

and I want to prove its "reverse form". So I have

```
Theorem plus_n_n_injective : forall n m,
     n + n = m + m ->
     n = m.
Proof.
  intros n. induction n as [| n' IHn'].
  - intros [] eq. reflexivity. discriminate.
  - intros m eq.
```

And then the goal is

```
1 goal
n' : nat
IHn' : forall m : nat, n' + n' = m + m -> n' = m
m : nat
eq : S n' + S n' = m + m
______________________________________(1/1)
S n' = m
```

So IMO, I want to rewrite the goal to `S n' + S n' = m + m` by `plus_id_example`. However, it fails with

```
rewrite <- plus_id_example
```

I don't know why.

Maybe it is because we can only rewrite like `a = b`. However, replacing it to `apply plus_id_example` does not work. And I don't know how to `apply ... with ...` with multiple replacement to take.

The only way is like

```
    pose proof plus_id_example as pp.
    specialize pp with (n := S n').
    specialize pp with (m := m).
```

My question is is there any way to do this with apply with or rewrite?

Meanwhile, I want to rewrite the goal to match `eq`, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send the command

```
rewrite <- plus_id_example.
```

The system analyzes the statements of `plus_id_example` and detects whether its conclusion is an equality (it is), and then it computes the *pattern* in the right hand side of this equality, here this pattern is:

```
(x + x)
```

where `x` can be replaced by any value (because the `m` in `plus_id_example` is universally quantified.

Then it looks in the conclusion of the goal for an instance of this pattern.

Here the conclusion of the goal is

```
S n' = m
```

So, there is no place where this rewrite can be applied, and the command fails.   This is the reason why you can't perform this precise rewrite command.

Anyway, the theorem `plus_id_example` is in fact not useful to prove the theorem `plus_n_n_injective`, you should think of another proof plan.

Comment: OK, but why can't I `apply` too? The `plus_id_example` theorem has `n + n = m + m -> n = m`. And if we consider `n:=(S n')` and `m:=m`, we apply this theorem to the goal IMO.

Comment: No, `plus_id_theorem` does not have the statement you write in the comment, according to your post.  The two sides of the arrow `->` do not play the same role.  Only the formula on the right hand-side of the arrow can be used for rewriting, and here it is `n + m = m + m`  the other equality formula is condition you have to verify, it happens to be an equality, but that equality cannot be used for rewriting.

Comment: So, it I have a H which is `A -> B` and I want to prove a goal which is `C -> B`, then I can apply H to get a new goal `C -> A`. However, if the goal is `C = B`, I can't apply H to get `C = B`?

Comment: The proof system breaks down the step in a more elementary way.  If you have a hypothesis H which *proves* `A -> B` and you want to prove a goal which is `C -> B`, you  cannot `apply H` directly, you first have to do `intros Hc` (and you then will also have an hypothesis Hc which proves `C`), only then, you can `apply H` and you get to a goal where you have to prove `A`, and then you can do `revert Hc`, which gets you a new goal `C -> A`.   For the other part of your question, with `C = B`, this usually does not happen, because we rarely write equality between propositions.

Comment: Anyway, the confusion in you initial question seems rather to come from understanding the difference between the statements on the right hand side of implications (which are proofs you should provide to  be able to use the theorem or hypothesis) and the right  and side (which is what the theorem or hypothesis gives you).  It is like the difference between giving and taking.